# How do I view all the rows in a data viewer?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have a data viewer attached to a data flow transformation to show me the incoming data in grid format. At the bottom of the grid, I see total rows as 22,002 but only 9,964 are rows displayed on the grid.  How do I view the remaining rows in the data viewer?  I've tried clicking and right-clicking on the data viewer but with no luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the data flow, SSIS pulls the data from your source into separate buffers which it manages separately down the data pipeline. In order to see the next buffer, you click the little play button in the top left hand corner which will then give you the second buffer. The number of rows displayed can be the same or different. By doing some quick math, SSIS probably generates about 2-3 buffers for you. You can easily copy and paste the data contained in each buffer by clicking the copy data button in the top right hand corner. I hope this clears up any confusion you had viewing data using the data viewer.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured the play button made the package continue running :-(

Comment: You might be able to increase the buffersize to hold the rows you need, it should then display everything